# Largest / Smallest from an array?

Tags: c++

currently stuck on a homework problem and hoping for some hints as to why my code isn't working / what I'm missing. The homework question asks you to make an array that holds a string of salsa flavors for a store, gathers data from the user input on how many were sold (jars) and then display the total sales from each flavor sold. Ive got all that down, but the question goes on to ask you to retrieve the best seller and the worst seller. I've attempted and can get my code to pull two flavors, but they're completely incorrect. Any help is appreciated! Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    int main()

    {
        // variables
        const int SIZE = 5;
        string salsas[SIZE] = { "Mild", "Medium", "Sweet", "Hot", "Zesty"}; 
        //names of salsas
        int jars[SIZE]; //holds number of jars user enters
        int sales[SIZE]; //holds sales numbers
        int count; //counts for a loop
        int largest; //largest sale
        int smallest; //smallest sale


        cout << "Enter the monthly number of jars sold for each type of 
        salsa.\n\n";

        // Display the salsas in the array
        for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++) 
        {
            cout << salsas[count] << ": ";
            cin >> jars[count];
        }

        // Display salsa sales
        cout << "\nEach jar of salsa, no matter the type, costs $5.50.\n";
        cout << "Here are the monthly sales numbers for each type of salsa. 
        \n\n";
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
        for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
        {
            double sales = jars[count] * 5.50;
            cout << salsas[count] << ": $";
            cout << sales << endl;  

        }

        //Gets highest sale
        {

        int count;
        int largest = sales[0];
        int index = 0;

        for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
        {
            if (sales[count] > largest)
            {
                largest = sales[count];
                index = count;
            }
        }

        cout << "\nBest Seller: " << salsas[index] << endl;
        }

            //Gets lowest sale
        {

        int count;
        int smallest = sales[0];
        int index = 0;

        for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
        {
            if (sales[count] < smallest)
            {
                smallest = sales[count];
                index = count;
            }
        }

        cout << "\nWorst Seller: " << salsas[index] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: So does `sales` (the array) represent how many are left, or how many were sold? Do they all start with the same original number?

Comment: Sorry, I left out some info, the user (shop owner) enters how many jars of a particular salsa flavor were sold in a one month period. the numbers can be made up. Sales is supposed to represent the number of jars sold for one particular flavor, multiplied by the price of the jar ($5.50 for each jar).

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest hindrances in debugging your own code is in naming your variables. If you've declared `count`, `largest`, and `smallest` variables at the start of your `main()` function but you redeclare them in a separate block later on. It's downright redundant.

The actual bug is that you're not actually calculating and filling your `sales[]` array. Comparing them later on for `largest` and `smallest` wouldn't work as intended.

Look for this line in the code below

```
sales[count] = jars[count] * 5.50;
```

#### Lé Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // variables
    const int SIZE = 5;
    string salsas[SIZE] = { "Mild", "Medium", "Sweet", "Hot", "Zesty"}; 
    //names of salsas
    int jars[SIZE]; //holds number of jars user enters
    int sales[SIZE]; //holds sales numbers

    // int count; //counts for a loop   //  no need
    // int largest; //largest sale      //  no need
    // int smallest; //smallest sale    //  no need

    cout << "Enter the monthly number of jars sold for each type of salsa.\n\n";

    // Display the salsas in the array
    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++) 
    {
        cout << salsas[count] << ": ";
        cin >> jars[count];
    }

    // Display salsa sales
    cout << "\nEach jar of salsa, no matter the type, costs $5.50.\n";
    cout << "Here are the monthly sales numbers for each type of salsa. \n\n";
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)  //  declare `count` where it is used
    {
        sales[count] = jars[count] * 5.50;      //  calculate sales[count]   IMPORTANT
        cout << salsas[count] << ": $";
        cout << sales[count] << endl;           //  show appropriate output

    }

    //Gets highest sale
    int largest = sales[0];     //  declare largest and index closest to where they are used
    int index = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
    {
        if (sales[count] > largest)
        {
            largest = sales[count];
            index = count;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nBest Seller: " << salsas[index] << endl;

    //Gets lowest sale
    int smallest = sales[0];    //  declare smallest closest to where it is used
    index = 0;                  //  reuse your old variable

    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
    {
        if (sales[count] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = sales[count];
            index = count;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nWorst Seller: " << salsas[index] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample Console Interaction

```
Enter the monthly number of jars sold for each type of salsa.

Mild: 20
Medium: 10
Sweet: 5
Hot: 2
Zesty: 1

Each jar of salsa, no matter the type, costs $5.50.
Here are the monthly sales numbers for each type of salsa. 

Mild: $110
Medium: $55
Sweet: $27
Hot: $11
Zesty: $5

Best Seller: Mild

Worst Seller: Zesty
```

Comment: You are crazy helpful, having the answer is nice, but tagging everything with an explanation is pure mercy. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please [vote and accept my answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks :-)